# How can I share a custom IntelliJ inspection?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have some custom IntelliJ inspections based on structural searching that I'd like to share with my team. I know that I can share an entire profile but that's not what I want. I want to share only this custom work I've written. Can that be done?

Comment: Try File | Export Settings, it works for custom inspections

Comment: That works to export them. But, you can't import it without overwriting your existing settings. Or, there's no way to merge it in.